# Import Excel Data without Inserting Into Table

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I am having some difficulty locating how to import data into Oracle SQL Developer without inserting the data into a table.

It seems all functions that I come across require users to insert into tables.

Does anyone know if there is a way to go about doing this? I do not have the access to create temp tables nor insert into existing tables.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "Import"? Normally "importing" means **exactly** to insert the data into an Oracle table. SQL Developer is only an interface application, what do you mean by importing "into SQL Developer"?

Comment: I want to import one column of data into my where clause and concatenate a string onto each record.

Comment: Example: where ID in Concate(<Imported List>,"STRING")

Comment: Are you using the imported data to update an Oracle table (do you have update permission?), or just to add it to some output that you are creating with a SELECT statement?  If the latter, consider copying the data from Oracle to another environment where you have permissions (e.g., local Postgres, MySQL, SQLite, etc.).

Comment: I'm essentially looking to add the data from my excel spreadsheet in my input to limit the output to only include the information found within the spreadsheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause:

```
WITH your_excel_data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  -- ...
  SELECT 9 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM   a_table
WHERE  a_value IN ( SELECT value FROM your_excel_data );
```

You can even generate the SQL statement within the sub-query factoring clause from your excel table:

```
="SELECT "&A1&" FROM DUAL UNION ALL"
```

Just adapt that so it points a the correct column and then copy and paste.